# Servlet Web Application Context from filter

Tags: spring, tomcat

I try to get the spring web application context from a filter.

I was previously getting it through:

```
WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(request.getServletContext())
```

It was ok, because I was getting what is called I think the ROOT web application context.
Now, I wanted to move all my spring definition like that in web.xml :

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <!-- Configure DispatcherServlet to use AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext instead of default XmlWebApplicationContext. --> 
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <!-- Custom web configuration annotated class. -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>foo.bar.WebConfiguration</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I removed the "old" definition from web.xml :

```
<!--    <context-param> -->
<!--        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> -->
<!--        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value> -->
<!--    </context-param> -->
<!--    <listener> -->
<!--        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class> -->
<!--    </listener> -->
```

Now, I have no more "ROOT" web application context, and the filter cannot get the another web application context.

I saw that there is another call :

```
WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(sc, attrName)
```

it allows to specify as second argument the "attribute", it is in fact the web application context you want.By default, it is "org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT".

I think I have to call this method but I don't know what to put as second parameter.

PS : I also tried to use org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy, but tomcat throwed the error that he dont find the classic (ROOT) web application context :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
```

BUT THERE IS ANOTHER CONTEXT, it is just defined in another way. It is not possible I am the only one trying to get another context that the ROOT.

Thanks to have read so far.

Comment: What if you have multiple dispatcherservlets? Which context to get then (there is a reason a `DelegatingFilterProxy` operates only on the root context, because there could be 0..n `DispatcherServlet`s with each its own context). The other way around (only a ROOT context) is easier then trying to obtain the other context. But if you really want the name is `org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.dispatcher` however as mentioned just using the root context is easier and more natural...

Comment: thanks I will try asap.
I would be glad that my context would be the ROOT one.
But I have the feeling that defining my context through `DispatcherServlet` instead of the old `ContextLoaderListener` make me have no ROOT context. Maybe is there a way that my context `DispatcherServlet` become the root one. Do you think this is possible? (I'll look for it tonight) Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I confirm your solution is working, thank you very much!
However I am still disturbed by what you said, that I should use the ROOT context.
So I've got the feeling my context is declared in the wrong way, it should be the ROOT one but it is not..
I will try to make it the ROOT one.

Comment: The root context is the one loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` not the one loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`s.

Answer (score 0):

I just read your answer, and yes I figured it out yesterday night ;-)
I added the ROOT context, defining it like that:

```
    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>foo.bar.WebConfiguration</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And its working, the filter can acces to the service directly with Autowiring.

I still have the feeling that my architecture is dirty because the ROOT and "dispatcher" context are the same, I think it's not a good practice.
Maybe I'll try later to split the "WebConfiguration" in two.

Thank you anyway!